# xcode ios project , how to import cpp code files from other directory?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I tried to put the CPP codes in a folder for unified management,
and provide them for Android and iOS platforms to compile and use together.

I've searched the Internet for several examples ,
but **none of them provide detailed steps**.

---

The directory structure for my experiment is as follows :

```
TestCppCrossPlatorm
 |---AndroidDemo     // for AndroidStudio to create a AndroidDemo
 |
 |---CommonCPP       // cpp files 
   |---Core.h
   |---Core.cpp
   |---myMath
     |---NumAdd.h
     |---NumAdd.cpp 
 |
 |---iOS_Demo       // for Xcode to create a iOS project
```

---

```
AndroidDemo
 |---app
    |---src
      |---main
         |---cpp
            |---CMakeLists.txt
            |---native-lib.cpp
         |---java
         |---res
```

A demo project created by AndroidStudio,
I configure in `CMakeFiles.txt` to add `CommonCPP` code files as follow :

```
include_directories(../../../../../CommonCPP)


add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             native-lib.cpp
            ../../../../../CommonCPP/Core.h
            ../../../../../CommonCPP/Core.cpp

            ../../../../../CommonCPP/myMath/NumAdd.h
            ../../../../../CommonCPP/myMath/NumAdd.cpp
        )
```

Edit `native-lib.cpp` :

```
#include "Core.h"            // test cpp code : Core.h
#include "myMath/NumAdd.h"   // test cpp code : NumAdd.h

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_sodino_demo_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {

    // code to try :  it's ok!
    std::string addResult = std::to_string(add(2, 3));
    const char* result = concatenateMyStringWithCppString(addResult.c_str());
//    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(result);
}
```

The code is working fine, and the demo is also running OK.

---

**There are some problems with the configuration of the iOS project**

A iOS demo project is created in the folder iOS_Demo by Xcode,

First, I add a `static library` named CommonCPP for iOS_Demo by the path `Build Settings -> Targets -> Add`,

Second, click `CommonCPP` target, select `Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> Add`, add `CommonCPP` folder, as follow :

[image]

Edit `ViewController.mm` to add `include Core.h and myMath/NumAdd.h`,

It failed ...
`'myMath/NumAdd.h' file not found`
[image]

Question 1 :
Why is all cpp files displayed in the Xcode below `Demo_iOS` instead of the `CommonCPP` target?

Question 2 :
Why `Core.h` can be include ok, but `myMath/NumAdd.h` failed? and how to fixed it?

---

examples without detailed steps : [How to use C++ for Cross-Platform Development](https://gusc.lv/2021/03/how-to-use-c-for-cross-platform-development/)

CMAKE is a good choice
But now, I'm more concerned about how to do it **step by step, and right**.

---

Core.h

```
#ifndef __HelloCpp__Core__
#define __HelloCpp__Core__

#include <iostream>

const char *concatenateMyStringWithCppString(const char *myString);

#endif /* defined(__HelloCpp__Core__) */
```

Core.cpp

```
#include <string.h>
#include "Core.h"
#include "myMath/NumAdd.h"

const char *CPP_BASE_STRING = "cpp says hello to %s";

const char *concatenateMyStringWithCppString(const char *myString) {
    char *concatenatedString = new char[strlen(CPP_BASE_STRING) + strlen(myString)];
    sprintf(concatenatedString, CPP_BASE_STRING, myString);


    return concatenatedString;
}
```

myMath/NumAdd.h

```
//
// Created by sodino on 2021/7/18.
//

#ifndef ANDROIDDEMO_NUMADD_H
#define ANDROIDDEMO_NUMADD_H

int add(int a, int b);


#endif //ANDROIDDEMO_NUMADD_H
```

myMath/NumAdd.cpp

```
//
// Created by sodino on 2021/7/18.
//

#include "NumAdd.h"
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: How did you fix this? I'm facing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you need to define the proper header path location for your libraries which will probably be something like `../CommonCPP`.

You'll want to add it to `Header Search Paths`. You can use `non-recursive` based on the way you are including your files. Note I did add an `Objective C++` file after I did the screenshot to verify it would build.

[image]

Note this is what the directory structure looks like:

[image]

You can adjust your path accordingly based on your Xcode project directory. But if it looks like mine, you can use the `../CommonCPP`.

Comment: Is this is the correct answer for this q, then you should be marking it as the accepted answer.